# In dplyr, how to join dataframes by columns that may or may not exist?

Tags: r, dplyr, merge, inner-join

I have two datafrmaes that I want to join. Whereas I always have a *main* mutual column to join by, I *sometimes* might have another column in the data that I will want to join by, in addition to the main one.

How could I specify a *possible* column to join by?

### Example

I demonstrate my question with two datasets derived from `mtcars`. Both have a "main" column (`cars`) that I will always join by, and sometimes there might be another mutual column (`some_letters`) in either one or both datasets.

```r
library(tidyverse)

create_df <- function(columns_to_include) {
  
  mtcars %>%
    rownames_to_column("cars") %>%
    select(cars, {{ columns_to_include }}) %>%
    slice_sample(n = 15) %>%
    {if (sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size = 1)) add_column(., some_letters = letters[1:15]) else .}
}

# both dataframes have "some_letters"
set.seed(123)
df_a1 <- create_df(carb)
df_a2 <- create_df(gear)
scenario_a <- inner_join(df_a1, df_a2, by = c("cars", "some_letters"))
scenario_a
#>             cars carb some_letters gear
#> 1 Ford Pantera L    4            l    5

# neither dataframe has "some_letters"
set.seed(111)
df_b1 <- create_df(carb)
df_b2 <- create_df(gear)
scenario_b <- inner_join(df_b1, df_b2, by = c("cars", "some_letters"))
#> Error: Join columns must be present in data.
#> x Problem with `some_letters`.

# one dataframe has "some_letters" but the other doesn't
set.seed(737)
df_c1 <- create_df(carb)
df_c2 <- create_df(gear)
scenario_c <- inner_join(df_c1, df_c2, by = c("cars", "some_letters"))
#> Error: Join columns must be present in data.
#> x Problem with `some_letters`.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

We can see that in `scenario_a` the join works because both `df_a1` and `df_a2` include `some_letters`. However, in `scenario_b` we see that the join fails because `some_letters` doesn't exist (in either data). Similarly, `scenario_c` shows a situation where `some_letters` appears in one dataset but not in the other and therefore the join fails.

When joining data, can I specify that `some_letters` is possible, but not guaranteed to appear, such that when it appears in both data it will become an additional join-by column, but otherwise it would be ignored from the `by` argument?

### Desired Output

```r
inner_join(df_b1, df_b2, by = c("cars", "some_letters"))

# as if we joined by `cars` only:

##                 cars carb gear
## 1      Porsche 914-2    2    5
## 2 Cadillac Fleetwood    4    3
## 3   Pontiac Firebird    2    3
## 4         Datsun 710    1    4
## 5          Merc 240D    2    4
## 6  Chrysler Imperial    4    3
## 7     Hornet 4 Drive    1    3
## 8         Camaro Z28    4    3
```

Comment: Why don't you simply create an if condition that checks if your desired column is available in the data set. If yes, then do the join by your two columns and if not do the join by just the first column.

Comment: @deschen because there might be many such possible columns in real situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a vector of `intersect`ing names

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
nm1 <- reduce(list(names(df_b1), names(df_b2),
             c("cars", "some_letters")), intersect)
```

and then do the join

```
inner_join(df_b1, df_b2, by =  nm1)
```

-output

```
#                cars carb gear
#1      Porsche 914-2    2    5
#2 Cadillac Fleetwood    4    3
#3   Pontiac Firebird    2    3
#4         Datsun 710    1    4
#5          Merc 240D    2    4
#6  Chrysler Imperial    4    3
#7     Hornet 4 Drive    1    3
#8         Camaro Z28    4    3
```

Comment: Fantastic. FYI I wrapped this in a function: `my_inner_join <- function(dat_1, dat_2, join_by_cols) {
  intersection_vec <- 
    reduce(list(names(dat_1), names(dat_2), join_by_cols),
           intersect)
  
  inner_join(dat_1, dat_2, by =  intersection_vec)
}`
calling `my_inner_join(df_b1, df_b2, join_by_cols = c("cars", "some_letters"))`